# zabbix timeout while connecting to 161

Tags: server, kubuntu, snmp, zabbix

I have a zabbix server, and I want to monitor an ubuntu 22.04 using SNMP

I used the following commands to install and set the snmp user for the ubuntu 22.04

```
$ sudo apt install snmp snmpd libsnmp-dev
$ net-snmp-create-v3-user -ro -a STrP@SSWRD -x STr0ngP@SSWRD -A SHA -X AES snmpadmin
$ sudo systemctl enable snmpd
$ sudo systemctl start snmpd
```

**BUT**, **on the zabbix Frontend**, when I create the host and set the credentials there, **the SNMP icon turns RED**

[zabbix screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gudzw.png)

EVEN snmpwalk timedout

```
user@ubuntuserver:~$ sudo snmpwalk -v3 -a SHA -A STrP@SSWRD -x AES -X STr0ngP@SSWRD -l authPriv -u snmpadmin 192.168.240.188
snmpwalk: Timeout
```

I'm not using any type of firewall BTW.

**Please Help!**